# If random variable $X$ has moments of all orders, does this imply that the moment generating function of $X$ exist?

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $EX^n<\infty$ for any $n$, does this imply that $M_X(t)=Ee^{tX}<\infty$ for all $t$ in some neighborhood of zero, that is, the moment generating function of $X$ exist?  If this is not true, a counterexample would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia has a paragraph where it explains that the log-normal distribution is a counterexample. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ce^{-\sqrt n}$  for $n <x<n+1$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ where $c$ is chosen such that $\int _0^{\infty} f(x)dx=1$. I will let you show that this is a density function of  a r.v. which has finite moments of all orders but $\int e^{tx} f(x)dx=\infty$ for every $t >0$. [It helps to write $tn-\sqrt n=\sqrt n (t\sqrt n -1)$. Get a lower bound for this on $(n,n+1)$].

As pointed out by Adayah below one can just take $f(x)=ce^{-\sqrt x}$ for all $x >0$.

Comment: What does it mean that $f(x) = ce^{-\sqrt{x}}$ for $n < x < n+1, n=1, 2, \ldots$? Are you defining one function $f$ or a sequence of functions $f_n$?

Comment: @Adayah There was a typo. It is one function.

Comment: Then why not just $f(x) = ce^{-\sqrt{x}}$? It's simpler and does the same job.

Comment: @Adayah Thanks. You are right. I will refer to your comment in  the answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score -3):

The series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nE(X^n)}{n!} $$
converges for all $t$ in a nbd of zero if and only the radius of convergence is positive, i.e. if and only if
$$ \overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{|E(X^n)|}{n!}\right)^{1/n}<\infty $$

Since $(n!)^{1/n}\approx (n/e)$ as $n\to\infty$, this imposes a growth
condition on the sequence $\frac{|E(X^n)|^{1/n}}{n}$. Thus, for example, if $X$ is bounded,  then the MGF will exist everywhere, (because the sequence $|E(X^n)|^{1/n}$ tends to the essential supremum of $X$ as $n\to\infty$) but in the general case one could have a MGF that converges nowhere.

Comment: "But in the general case one could have a MGF that converges nowhere". That is, in point of fact, the question: to prove that there is a random variable where all the moments exist but the MGF converges only in $0$. Beware that you cannot freely assign the moments of a random variable.

Comment: Not exactly. The question is "does this imply..." etc, and the answer is No. Of course a counterexample would be helpful, but it was already given by someone else. I believe my answer adds useful information, but you may of course opt to disagree.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your last comment (nor am I sure I want to). *Either the assertion is a theorem*, in which case it is arguably implied by apparently weaker statements than the hypothesis explicitly listed in the post, *or it isn't a theorem*, in which case hopefully its negation is a theorem. Your post has an important leap in logic which I've already mentioned and will not repeat.

Comment: I don't understand you either, so don't feel too bad about it. This is not an exam conducted by you or anyone else. It is an open forum for interested parties to exchange ideas. And by all means, please do not repeat.